# Параллелепипед на CSS. Проблема с боковой гранью

Tags: css, 3d

https://jsfiddle.net/nevolgograd/v4ac3g7w/

```
#wrapper {
  perspective: 1500px;
}
#cube {
    position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% -50vh;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  // transition: all cubic-bezier(.21,.66,.43,.82) 5s;
  transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
}
.side {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
  background-color: #BADA55;
  opacity: .5;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px dashed #cf0ae6;
    transform-origin: 50% 50% -50vh;
    // -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#menu-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: nowrap row;
    justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: #9efff0;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#side2{     
    transform: rotateY(90deg);
    width: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}
#side3{     
    transform: rotateY(-90deg);
    width: 100vh;
}
#side4{ transform: rotateX(90deg); }
#side5{ transform: rotateX(-90deg); }
#side6{ transform: rotateY(180deg); }
```

Тут, собственно, весь код. 
Проблема в том, что боковая грань находится внутри фигуры. Никак не могу сообразить в чем проблема.

Comment: Размером экрана можно подогнать :D А ещё, это параллелепипед.

Comment: У меня в голове собаки нагадили, уже не соображаю. Да, параллелепипед конечно, опечатался. right: 0 для грани помогает, но при изменении ширины экрана транзишин плавно двигает блок. Как бы его там зафиксировать?

Comment: Какая из них, красная?

Comment: А-то. Не зря же она красная.

Answer (score 1):

Смените центр трансформации:

```
#side2 {
    ...
    transform-origin: 50vw 50% -50vw;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ep73m1gn/

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
#side2 {
    transform: rotateY(90deg);
    width: 100vh;
    background-color: red;
    right: 0;
}
```

И у `#cube` уберите `transition`

Comment: Кубу всяко нужен транзишн. Поменял all на transform. Спасибо за намек.